# Selecting empty character column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, select

I want to select some rows from a SQLite table, and add an empty character column at the same time, but I get an error.  The statement is SELECT firstname, SPACE(100) AS mytext FROM Customers, and the error message is "No such function: space".

I can run the same command in SQL-server without any probems, and in SQLite I can select additional numeric columns without problems (eg. SELECT firstname, 8 AS newfield ...), but not character columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,  Alan

Comment: Functions are not standard across database engines; some will be the same, but most are not. A complete list of standard functions is here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html. You can also create custom functions in C, C#, or whatever you're using.

Comment: @Samuel - thanks for the reply.  From the core function list it looks like SQLite is severely lacking in the function department compared to other databases.  Unfortunately I don't know C or C#, my main language is Python.  Regards.

Comment: You can create custom sqlite functions in python. Look at create_function. http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: @Samuel - thanks for the customised function tip - I'll look into it.  Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are not standard across database engines; some will be the same, but most are not. A complete list of standard functions is here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html. You can also create custom functions in C, C#, or whatever you're using.

There is no built in version of SPACE. You need to create a custom function or use a string literal.